# Browser compatibility of css positioning (chrome vs. firefox)

Tags: html, css, browser

I have an issue with the compatibility of range element positionings in firefox. Everything works fine in chrome and safari. However, the vertical spacing between the range elements is enhanced in firefox, which I do not want. How can I equal the vertical spacing between chrome and firefox?

I use the following html code:

```
<input class="pos_row1_1" id="slider1" max="100" min="0" onkeydown="return
false;" step="1" type="range" value="0" />

<input class="pos_row1_2" id="slider2" max="100" min="0" onkeydown="return
false;" step="1" type="range" value="0" />

<input class="pos_row1_3" id="slider3" max="100" min="0" onkeydown="return
false;" step="1" type="range" value="0" />
```

and the css code for the shifted sliders:

```
input[type="range"] {
 margin-left: 50px;
}
.pos_row1_1 {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
}
.pos_row1_2  {
 position: relative;
 left: 120px;
}
.pos_row1_3  {
position: relative;
left: 220px;
}
```

How it looks currently:

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIiuu.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzyZ1.png)

Of course, I did a proper CSS reset. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not really a 'solution', but you could target either firefox or chrome with a CSS hack like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/) and add up for the spacing.

Comment: Thank you, does work for me.

Comment: Glad to help :)